# Scripting Trac installation on Windows

Tags: windows, scripting, automation, trac

I'm currently working on some R&D for improving the process and practice that we approach development.

As a first iteration something I'd like to do is develop an easy way to set up a project e.g. Run an ant script that will, when provided with a project name etc,

1. Copy a template in svn
2. Create a database (if needed)
3. Automatically update the connection strings in config/properties files
4. Create an instance of trac
5. Email the user with all this information

I'm fine with the first 4 but I'm struggling to get a good process together for setting up Trac.

I've done it manually before but found it incredibily difficult.

Does anyone know of such a set up script or have any tips on doing this?

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at bitnami?

See the [Trac bitnami bundle](http://bitnami.org/stack/trac) for example